# select and combine 2 arrays in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have a Input json below

```
[
    {
        "fileName": "abc",
        "value": [
            {
                "SSC": {
                    "Payload": [
                        {
                            "Ledger": [
                                {
                                    "Line": [
                                        {
                                            "AccountingCode": [
                                                "402050046767"
                                            ],
                                            "AccountingPeriod": [
                                                "00720201243"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "AccountingCode": [
                                                "203010334567"
                                            ],
                                            "AccountingPeriod": [
                                                "00720201234"
                                            ]
                                            
                                        }
                                       
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "fileName": "abc",
        "value": [
            {
                "SSC": {
                    "Payload": [
                        {
                            "Ledger": [
                                {
                                    "Line": [
                                        {
                                            "AccountingCode": [
                                                "40205004"
                                            ],
                                            "AccountingPeriod": [
                                                "0072020"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "AccountingCode": [
                                                "20301033"
                                            ],
                                            "AccountingPeriod": [
                                                "0072020"
                                            ]
                                            
                                        }
                                       
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

my expected output is

```
[
    {
        "fileName": "abc",
        "value": [
            {
                "SSC": {
                    "Payload": [
                        {
                            "Ledger": [
                                {
                                    "Line": [
                                        {
                                            "AccountingCode": [
                                                "402050046767"
                                            ],
                                            "AccountingPeriod": [
                                                "00720201243"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "AccountingCode": [
                                                "203010334567"
                                            ],
                                            "AccountingPeriod": [
                                                "00720201234"
                                            ]
                                            
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "AccountingCode": [
                                                "40205004"
                                            ],
                                            "AccountingPeriod": [
                                                "0072020"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "AccountingCode": [
                                                "20301033"
                                            ],
                                            "AccountingPeriod": [
                                                "0072020"
                                            ]
                                            
                                        }
                                       
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Below is the xslt i have tried but not getting the proper output

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    
    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:variable name="input-as-xml" select="json-to-xml($input)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="transformed-xml" as="element(array)">
           <array>
            
                           <map>  
                    <string key="fileNames">
                        <xsl:for-each select="$input-as-xml//string[@key='fileName']">
                            <xsl:variable name="file" select="../string[@key='fileName']"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$file"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </string>
                               <array key="value">
                                   <map>
                                       <array key="SSC">
                                           <map>
                                               <array key="Payload">
                                                   <map>
                                                       <array key="Ledger">
                                                           <xsl:for-each select="$input-as-xml//array[@key='Ledger']">
                                                               
                                                           
                                                           <map>
                                                           <xsl:choose>
                                                               <xsl:when test="$input-as-xml//string[@key='fileName'] = 'abc'">
                                                                   <xsl:value-of select="$input-as-xml//array[@key='Lines']"/>
                                                                 
                                                                       
                                                               </xsl:when>
                                                           </xsl:choose>
                                                           </map>
                                                           </xsl:for-each>
                                                           
                                                       </array>
                                                   </map>
                                               </array>
                                           </map>
                                       </array>
                                   </map>
                               </array>
                           </map>
            
           </array>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($transformed-xml)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am tring to select Array "Lines" from the json if the file name is abc then combine the value of the selected in Array "Ledger"

Please can anyone help me understand how to achieve this in xslt.

Comment: As so often, it raises the question how much of your input is fixed, and how much is variable? Will it always be an array of exactly two entries having the same fileName, and what should happen if it isn't?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without converting to XML and back again: just manipulate the JSON as a structure of maps and arrays. Something along the lines of

```
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <xsl:variable name="in" select="json-doc('input.json')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="out" as="map(*)*">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$in?*" group-by="?fileName">
      <xsl:map>
        <xsl:map-entry key="'fileName'" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <xsl:map-entry key="'value'" select="
           array {
             map {'SSC': 
               map {'Payload': 
                 array {
                   map {'Ledger':
                     array {
                       map{'Line': array:join(current-group()?
                                    value?*?SSC?Payload?*?Ledger?*?Line)}
                     }
                   }
               }
            }"/>
       </xsl:map>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:sequence select="array{$out}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I haven't tested this and there are probably a few bugs in the complex path to iron out, but I hope it conveys the idea.

(Note, this would be easier if XSLT 3.0 had an `xsl:array` instruction. If you're prepared to use Saxon extensions, there's a `saxon:array` that plugs this gap.)